# for loop stopping at first element/ something needs to be in an element for loop to continue

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine, inventory

I have a crafting menu script that depending on what you click on in the game menu it will loop through the slots of the inventory and look to see if you have a certain object of a certain name in your inventory.

It is not working as planned though.

If the object being searched for is in the 1st element of the array the for loop is working through than everything will work fine.
Visual guide: [http://imgur.com/e1cr8bX](https://imgur.com/e1cr8bX)

If all the slots in the inventory array leading up to the one being searched for are filled with other objects then everything will work fine.
Visual guide: [http://imgur.com/aVNw8JE](https://imgur.com/aVNw8JE)

But if there is no object in one of the slots leading up to the object being searched for than the loop just seems to stop and nothing happens. 
Visual guide: [http://imgur.com/qYO3mPJ](https://imgur.com/qYO3mPJ)

I've tried adding if statements to do certain things if a slot returns null. Things like Debug.Log and j++. But neither do anything.

Here is the script:

```
void Update () {
    //Loop through inventory slots.
    for (int j = 0; j < itemstacks.Length; j++)
    {            
        if (playerInventory.itemStacks[j].stackSize == 0)
        {
            playerInventory.itemStacks[j] = null;
        }

        //Loop through shop slots.
        for (int i = 0; i < slots.Length; i++)
        {
            if (IsMouseOverSlot(i))
            {
                if (CraftMenuINVScript.CraftMenuStacks[i] != null)
                {
                    if (CraftMenuINVScript.CraftMenuStacks[i].item.name == "WalkWay")
                    {
                        if (itemstacks[j].item.name == "Log")
                        {
                            if (playerInventory.itemStacks[j].stackSize >= 2)
                            {
                                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                                {
                                     Debug.Log("Craft");
                                     playerInventory.AddItem(CraftMenuINVScript.CraftMenuStacks[i].item.name, 1);
                                     playerInventory.itemStacks[j].stackSize -= 2;
                                }
                            }  
                        }
                        else if (itemstacks[j].item.name == null)
                        {
                            Debug.Log("yo");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("No item");
                }
            }
        }           
        RenderShopSlots();
    }
}
```

I'm sure I am an idiot and there is something staring me right in the face but I can't seem to fix this issue. I can think of work arounds like having to put the inventory objects in certain places slots for things to happen. But I'd rather get it to work this way.

Also I've only been using c# for a few months now so please don't grill me too hard if I'm making some stupid noobie errors.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried to debug through the breakpoints? if not, try it and you should be able to see where the program exits the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Because I've only been coding for a few months I'm not well versed in all the terminology.

Is a breakpoint after each if statement? If so I have added Debug.Log after each to see if they stop getting called.

They all are called. Except for the if(itemstacks[j].item.name == "Log")
That is called only in the examples I provided in my post.

Comment: Try debugging line by line with breakpoint and you should be able to identify the problematic code by yourself. You can take help from msdn:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx

Comment: Check the error log.  I think you are getting a null reference exception.  Should the for loop be in an else?

Comment: Which for loop? Also I do get a null reference exception. When I hover over "WalkWay" I get one for the line `if (itemstacks[j].item.name == "Log")`. But the thing is if I don't have an item called Log in the inventory nothing happens when I mouse down on the "walkway". But if I do the code runs? It adds the item "Walkway" to the inventory? The error log is saying reference not set not set to an instance of an object and yet the code runs like it is?

Comment: You should probably comment your code a bit. I have no idea what's the difference between itemstacks and playerInventory.itemStacks.